# How to set parameters before simuliting to make it more consist to the real road net? (in SUMO)

Tags: sumo

In order to make the simulation more consist to the real road, we should reset some traffic parameters in SUMO,such as max vehical speed, Max acceleration, minGAP e.t.
Which parameters need to be set in SUMO? And how?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic question and it really depends on what you want to model and which input data you have. For starters you could try to calibrate the vehicle maximum speed acceleration and deceleration from observation points. using an iterative optimization. This is described in detail in https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Tutorials/Calibration/San_Pablo_Dam.html
The resulting parameters can then be put into the vType for your vehicle.